# Number of representations by indefinite quadratic forms

Tags: analytic-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, binary-quadratic-forms

Let $Q(x,y) = a x^2 + b x y + c y^2$ be a quadratic form with **positive** discriminant $d = b^2 - 4 a c > 0$. Is it true that the number of solutions to $Q(x,y) = n$ is bounded above by $\ll_{\varepsilon} (d n)^{\varepsilon}$ for any fixed $\varepsilon > 0$ ?

The question is motivated by the fact that the bound $\ll_{\varepsilon} n^{\varepsilon}$ is true for quadratic forms with **negative** discriminant, since the number of representations is then upper bounded by the number of ideal classes of an imaginary quadratic field with norm $n$. The latter is equal to the coefficient of the Dedekind zeta function of an imaginary quadratic field and is then by the divisor bound $\ll_{\varepsilon} n^{\varepsilon}$ for every fixed $\varepsilon > 0$. However I struggle to find results in the literature pertaining to forms with positive discriminant.

Comment: if the discriminant is not a square, the form has an infinite automorphism group, so that any represented number $n$ is represented infinitely often. I guess you ought to look up the Pell equation.

Comment: Thank you, you are right, I forgot about the Pell equation and that is perhaps the single most important example of an indefinite quadratic form.